# Including several tables in tex format in my main document

Tags: r, knitr, tex

Is there a way to generate tables in tex format in R and then call them in my *.rnw file 
I have to geenerate a lot of tables using some userdefined function and then use them in my latex file through sweave/knitr.
Here is a simplified example to illustrate my point...

Data:

```
x1 <- round(rnorm(10),2)
x2 <- sample(c('a','b','c'),10,replace=TRUE)

data1 <- cbind(x1,noquote(x2));data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
names(data1)=c('X1','X2')
```

Now I want to put this `data1` in a tex file as follows

```
latex(data1,file='myfile.tex')
```

When running the above in my sweave document R-studio was getting stuck in the sense that the process would not end. 
I get the following error

```
 No file file1170690e2c79.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
[1] (C:\Users\~~~\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeuvW08\file1170690e2c79.aux) )
Output written on file1170690e2c79.dvi (1 page, 604 bytes).
Transcript written on file1170690e2c79.log.
```

So, I used the following

```
sink('myfile.tex')
latex(data1,file='')
sink()
```

**I guess there might be a better way. I do not not what mistake I am doing in the latex command.**
I would appreciate if someone can help me with this by providing me a better approach

---

Here is my sweave file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\title{Untitled}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


<<somechunk,results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
x1 <- round(rnorm(10),2)
x2 <- sample(c('a','b','c'),10,replace=TRUE)
data1 <- cbind(x1,noquote(x2));data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
names(data1)=c('X1','X2')
sink('myfile.tex')

latex(data1,file='')
sink()
@

Here is my table 1 \include{myfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why not `latex(data1, file='')` directly? I mean why you have to create the tex file first, then `\include{yourfile}` manually? this will bring you maintenance troubles because you have to take care of both source code and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the other answers, the easiest 
(with `Hmisc::latex` or `xtable`) 
is usually to generate the LaTeX code only when needed.

If this is not possible, the following should work:

```
tmp <- latex(data1,file='myfile.tex')
```

What happens is that `latex` creates the file
and returns an object of class `latex`.
The `print` method is then called, but it tries to compile the file
and display the results, which is not desired in your case.
Assigning the result to a variable (which will not be used),
or wrapping the call in `invisible`, suppresses the call to `print`.

```
invisible( latex(data1,file='myfile.tex') )
```

Comment: That is right. You have to prevent `print.latex` which will be called when you implicitly print the latex object returned by `latex()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the xtable package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

<<somechunk,results=tex,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
library(xtable)
x1 <- round(rnorm(10),2)
x2 <- sample(c('a','b','c'),10,replace=TRUE)
data1 <- cbind(x1,noquote(x2));data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
names(data1)=c('X1','X2')
@

Here is my table 1:

<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
xtable(data1)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know xtable will work in this simplified example but the table I would need to generate would require latex function. Thank you @ EDi